# can grafana group by multiple columns when work with influxdb

Tags: influxdb, grafana

when I use influxdb as the datasource, In the graph metrics define, I find that if I add a column after the "and" label, (like: latency_scope, type), data response is correct but legend display undefine, and there is no date display on the dashboard.

raw query is like this, however, it does not work.
"select latency_scope,  uri, sum(sum_count) from "latency" where $timeFilter group by time($interval), latency_scope,  uri fill(0) order asc"

Can grafana make multiple group by?

thx

Answer (score -1):

I just checked the code, and that's true it does not support multiple group by, but it is not difficult to modify the source code to support.